# Pandas: Fill the table between start date and event date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

| contract | start month | break month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | Jan 2023 | Apr 2023 |
| Id2 | Feb 2023 | Feb 2023 |

How could I convert it in report in Python so that every month between start month and break month has it's own column? Start month should be included, but the break month should not.

Desired output:

| contract | report date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | Jan 2023 | 1 |
| Id1 | Feb 2023 | 1 |
| Id1 | Mar 2023 | 1 |

I think to apply a cycle, but can't understand how.
My real dataframe has more than 2 million ids/rows.

Comment: to clarify - every month up until (but not including) the final month should be included? So for Jan 2023 - Dec 2023, it would be 11 months?

Comment: What is the `flag` column? Is it always supposed to be 1?

Comment: @Mark yes. You understand it right

Comment: @not_speshal flag is always =1

Comment: thanks for that! also right to assume that 'Dataframe > 2 mln Id's.' means your df has more than 2 million ids?

Comment: Welcome to SO! And hopefully this is only me: I find this line unclear: *Contract - just Id's Start month - the month when Id appear Break date - date of event when Id must be removed from the report.* Is it a compacted bullet point?

Comment: in that case, it might be worth looking at the overlaps of the intervals. Mozway's solution is very elegant, (as always ;) ), but it's unclear to me how performant it would be on a large dataset

Comment: @OCa just trying describe :)

Comment: @Mark hopefully quite efficient, repeating is cheap, though computation of `n` is not vectorized :)

Comment: @Mark took ~7s for 2M rows on my computer

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['start month'], format='%b %Y').dt.to_period('M')
b = pd.to_datetime(df['break month'], format='%b %Y').dt.to_period('M')
n = b.sub(s).apply(lambda d: d.n)

out = (df.assign(**{'Report date': s, 'flag': 1})
   .loc[df.index.repeat(n)]
   .assign(**{'Report date': lambda d: d['Report date']
                                       .add(d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
                                      #.dt.strftime('%b %Y')
                                     ,})
   [['contract', 'Report date', 'flag']]
)
```

Alternative syntax:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['start month'], format='%b %Y').dt.to_period('M')
b = pd.to_datetime(df['break month'], format='%b %Y').dt.to_period('M')
n = b.sub(s).apply(lambda d: d.n)

out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(n), ['contract']]
         .join(s.rename('Report date'))
         .assign(**{'Report date': lambda d: d['Report date']
                                             .add(d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
                                            #.dt.strftime('%b %Y')
                                            ,
                    'flag': 1
                   })
       )
```

Output:

```
  contract Report date  flag
0      Id1     2023-01     1
0      Id1     2023-02     1
0      Id1     2023-03     1
```

With formatting of date:

```
  contract Report date  flag
0      Id1    Jan 2023     1
0      Id1    Feb 2023     1
0      Id1    Mar 2023     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `groupby` and `resample`:

```
df["start month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start month"], format="%b %Y")
df["break month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["break month"], format="%b %Y")

stacked = df.set_index("contract").stack()
stacked = stacked.reset_index(name="month").assign(flag=1)

output = stacked.groupby("contract").resample("M",on="month")["flag"].last().ffill().reset_index()
output = output[output["month"].ne(output.groupby("contract")["month"].transform("max"))]
output["month"] = output["month"].dt.strftime("%b %Y")

>>> output
  contract     month  flag
0      Id1  Jan 2023   1.0
1      Id1  Feb 2023   1.0
2      Id1  Mar 2023   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) of the *start/break* months :

```
out = (
    df.assign(
        report_date= [
            pd.date_range(st, br, freq="MS", inclusive="left").strftime("%b %Y")
            for st, br in zip(df.pop("start month"), df.pop("break month"))
            ], flag=1).explode("report_date") # replicating the date ranges
        .loc[lambda s: s["contract"].duplicated(keep=False)]
        .reset_index(drop=True) # this chain could be optional
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  contract report_date  flag
0      Id1    Jan 2023     1
1      Id1    Feb 2023     1
2      Id1    Mar 2023     1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is bit loopy. But it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'contact': ['id1', 'id2'],
                   'start_month': ['jan-2023', 'feb-2023'],
                   'break_month': ['apr-2023', 'feb-2023']})


df['start_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_month'], format = '%b-%Y')
df['break_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['break_month'], format = '%b-%Y')

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i, id in enumerate(df.contact.unique()):

        
    x = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = df[df['contact'] == id].start_month[i], end= df[df['contact'] == id].break_month[i],
                      freq='M', inclusive='left'), columns = ['report_date'])
    x['contact'] = id
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, x] , axis = 0)

print(df1)

report_date contact
0  2023-01-31     id1
1  2023-02-28     id1
2  2023-03-31     id1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example usage:
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'contract': ['Id1', 'Id2'],
  'start month': ['Jan 2023', 'Feb 2023'],
  'break month': ['Apr 2023', 'Mar 2023'],
})
print(df)


start_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['start month'], format='%b %Y')
break_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['break month'], format='%b %Y')
"""print(start_dates)
0   2023-01-01
1   2023-02-01
Name: start month, dtype: datetime64[ns]
print(break_dates)
0   2023-04-01
1   2023-03-01
Name: break month, dtype: datetime64[ns]
"""

all_dates = pd.date_range(start=start_dates.min(), end=break_dates.max(), freq='M')
"""print(all_dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
"""

# Use np.floor_divide or // for integer division
# Assuming 30 days per month
month_diff =  (break_dates - start_dates).dt.days // 30

"""print(month_diff)
0    3
1    0"""

aa = {i : d for i, d in enumerate(month_diff)}
"""print(aa)
{0: 3, 1: 0}
"""

bb =  [start_dates[i] + pd.Series(range(d)) * pd.DateOffset(days=1) for i,d in enumerate(month_diff)]
print(bb)

"""print(bb)
[0    2023-01-01 00:00:00
1    2023-01-02 00:00:00
2    2023-01-03 00:00:00
dtype: object, Series([], dtype: object)]"""

bb1 = np.concatenate(bb)
"""print(bb1)
[Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00') Timestamp('2023-01-02 00:00:00')
 Timestamp('2023-01-03 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00') Timestamp('2023-01-02 00:00:00')
 Timestamp('2023-01-03 00:00:00')]"""


cc = np.repeat(df['contract'].values,month_diff)
"""print(cc)
['Id1' 'Id1' 'Id1']
"""
report_dates  = pd.DataFrame({'contract' : cc , 'Report_date' : bb1}) 

"""print(report_dates)
 contract Report_date
0      Id1  2023-01-01
1      Id1  2023-01-02
2      Id1  2023-01-03
"""
# Mark relevant dates and add flag
out = report_dates.merge(df[['contract','break month']], how='left', on='contract')

"""print(out)
  contract Report_date break month
0      Id1  2023-01-01    Apr 2023
1      Id1  2023-01-02    Apr 2023
2      Id1  2023-01-03    Apr 2023

"""
out['flag'] = np.where(out['Report_date'] <= out['break month'],1,0 )
"""print(out)
 contract Report_date break month  flag
0      Id1  2023-01-01    Apr 2023     1
1      Id1  2023-01-02    Apr 2023     1
2      Id1  2023-01-03    Apr 2023     1
"""
```

Method 2 :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'contract': ['Id1', 'Id2'],
  'start month': ['Jan 2023', 'Feb 2023'],
  'break month': ['Apr 2023', 'Mar 2023'],
})
print(df)
# Convert text dates to datetime objects
start_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['start month'], format='%b %Y')
break_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['break month'], format='%b %Y')

# Find earliest start and latest break date across all contracts
all_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_dates.min(), end=break_dates.max(), freq='M')
"""print(all_date_range)
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
"""

contract_date_pairs =  [zip(np.repeat(contract,len(dr)),dr) 
                        for contract,dr in zip(df['contract'],[all_date_range ])]

all_possible_report_dates = pd.Series(list(chain(*contract_date_pairs)))
"""
print(all_possible_report_dates)

0    (Id1, 2023-01-31 00:00:00)
1    (Id1, 2023-02-28 00:00:00)
2    (Id1, 2023-03-31 00:00:00)
"""
# Extract contract and date information
contracts = pd.Series([x[0] for x in all_possible_report_dates])
"""print(contracts)
0    Id1
1    Id1
2    Id1"""

report_dates = pd.to_datetime([x[1] for x in all_possible_report_dates])

"""print(report_dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)"""
"""
print(break_dates.max())
2023-04-01 00:00:00
"""
# Generate flags
flags = np.where(report_dates <= break_dates.max(), 1, 0)
"""
print(flags) 
[1 1 1]
"""
# Create the final DataFrame
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'contract': contracts, 'Report date': report_dates, 'flag': flags})
"""print(final_df)
  contract Report date  flag
0      Id1  2023-01-31     1
1      Id1  2023-02-28     1
2      Id1  2023-03-31     1
"""
# Optional: Reset index for desired format
final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)

"""print(final_df)
  contract Report date  flag
0      Id1  2023-01-31     1
1      Id1  2023-02-28     1
2      Id1  2023-03-31     1
"""
```

Intermediates :

```
aa = [ print(contract,':',dr)  for contract, dr in  zip(df['contract'],[all_date_range])]

"""print(aa)
Id1 : DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
[None]"""

bb = [ print( np.repeat(contract,len(dr))   )  for contract, dr in  zip(df['contract'],[all_date_range])]

"""print(bb)
['Id1' 'Id1' 'Id1']"""

cc = [ print( np.repeat(contract,len(dr)),dr )  for contract, dr in  zip(df['contract'],[all_date_range])]

"""print(cc)
['Id1' 'Id1' 'Id1'] DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
"""

dd =  [ print( list(chain(*[zip(np.repeat(contract,len(dr)),dr)])) )  for contract, dr in  zip(df['contract'],[all_date_range])]

"""print(dd)
[('Id1', Timestamp('2023-01-31 00:00:00')),
 ('Id1', Timestamp('2023-02-28 00:00:00')),
 ('Id1', Timestamp('2023-03-31 00:00:00'))]
[None]"""

ee = [ print(pd.Series(list(chain(*[zip(np.repeat(contract,len(dr)),dr)]))))  for contract, dr in  zip(df['contract'],[all_date_range])]

"""print(ee)
0    (Id1, 2023-01-31 00:00:00)
1    (Id1, 2023-02-28 00:00:00)
2    (Id1, 2023-03-31 00:00:00)
dtype: object"""
```